# Can I split helper modules into different files using ExUnit with Mix?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, ex-unit

A couple failed attempts and the documentation [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.html#module-integration-with-mix) leads me to believe that I have to either define helper modules in `test/test_helper.exs` or in one of the other `test/*.exs` files nested under a module (that `use ExUnit.Case`) in my mix project. Is there a way to define these modules in their own files so that tests can use them, without cluttering up `test/test_helper.exs` or putting them under `lib/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `mix.exs` file you define different paths for different environments in the project declaration (inside `Mix.Project.project/0` callback, key `elixirc_paths`:

```
defmodule MyApp.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      ...
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env()),
      ...
    ]
  end
```

Then you provide different clauses for different environments:

```
defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/helpers"]
defp elixirc_paths(_), do: ["lib"]
```

The paths above will be added to what Elixir compiles and all the code in `test/helpers` dir will become available in the runtime *when running the project in `test` environment only*.

Comment: Awesome. That worked, thank you. One more detail is that the helper modules should have the `.ex` extension. I figured it out eventually.

Comment: @matthiasdenu well, I guessed the mandatory _compiled module_ extension `ex` (as opposed to _elixir script_ `exs`)  is out of scope here since it’s the Elixir-wide convention that has basically nothing to do with the OP :)